# removing duplicate records based on has many relationship in database level

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a products table, that has many variants. Each variant has two records in the option_variant table including size and color Ids. For some reason, duplicate variants was created for products. Meaning that, a product has more than one variant with the same color and size. My question is how can I find and delete these duplicate variants at the database level. There are too many records in the table and I do not want to handle the situation in PHP code.
My application was written with Laravel 8 (PHP) and using MariaDB 10.4 for storing data.
[Database design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/995U5.jpg)

Comment: Whilst you’ve provided a relatively detailed explanation and background of your issue, you’ve not provided any code or described where you’re having issues. StackOverflow is a debugging service, not a code writing service. Show us what you’ve tried and where you’re stuck and we’ll be happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using following query:

```
DB::table('option_variant as v1')
        ->join('option_variant AS v2', function ($join) {
            $join->on('v2.variant_id', '=', 'v1.variant_id');
            $join->on('v2.option_id', '<>', 'v1.option_id');
        })
        ->join('variants', 'variants.variant_id', '=', 'v1.variant_id')
        ->selectRaw('
            concat(v1.option_id, ".", v2.option_id) as combined_options,
            group_concat(variants.variant_id) as combined_variants,
            count(variants.variant_id) as variants_count,
            variants.variant_id
            ',
        )
        ->groupBy('product_id' ,'combined_options')
        ->havingRaw('count(variants.variant_id) > 1')
        ->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQL triggers is the other option when you want to handle validation in a place other than php, you need to study them if you haven't.

I can't comment because I'm below 50

Comment: Never do that, as the database is just a source of truth, it must not have logic in it or it will be super complex to maintain

Comment: @matiaslauriti is it good to use it for keeping firstname and lastname of users unique? (these types of situations in general.)

Comment: Yes, just try to avoid custom db functions, and store procedures, the idea is that the framework holds that type of logic